Integration of a |exp(-t)sint| from 0 to infinity
$$
\mbox{What would be the integration of}\ \left\vert\exp\left(-2t\right)\sin\left(t\right)\right\vert\ \mbox{from}\ 0\ \mbox{to}\ \infty\ ?.
$$

The problem I am facing here is that when I apply modulus across $\sin\left(t\right)$ it becomes a full wave rectified sine wave. So how should I handle this in the integration $\ ?$.

It would be kind if you could show me the step by step procedure.

You have to do the half-period intervals $[0,]pi]$, $[\pi,2\pi]$, etc. separately and add the results.

As I have said the upper limit is infinity, so for how many intervals should this be calculated can't be measured right? So how can I do that?@Steen82

Infinitely many, but there should be a pattern.

Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3452387/686284
